# VB.net set UAC publisher name

Tags: vb.net, uac, prompt, publisher

How do i set the [publisher name in the UAC prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67rE7.png) with VB.net?

Comment: @Mark I tried that already.

Comment: Is your cert from a trusted CA (trusted by the user running the application, in certmgr.msc)?